# SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio is throwing an error on Temporal Table creation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio 2022 and I want to create a temporal table with data retention for 12 months.
When I wrote this in SSMS the script works but when I move it to Visual Studio project it errors out.

Could you please advise if there is something I'm missing here to make this work?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Franchises]
(
    [FranchiseID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [ShortName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [ModifiedBy] NVARCHAR(250) NULL, 
    [ModifiedOn] DATETIME NULL DEFAULT GetDate(), 
    [CreatedBy] NVARCHAR(250) NULL, 
    [CreatedOn] DATETIME NULL DEFAULT GetDate(),     
    [StartDate] DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL, 
    [EndDate] DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL, 
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartDate, EndDate), 
)
WITH
(
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON 
    (
        HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.FranchiseHistory,
        DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = OFF,
        History_retention_period = 12 MONTHS
    )
)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbzhM.png

I ran the script in SSMS and it worked, the same script in Visual Studio Database project throws an exception.
I have attached the image in my question.

Comment: Try removing the trailing comma `PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartDate, EndDate),`

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have `select @@version`

Comment: FWIW "It's highly recommended to set SYSTEM_VERSIONING with DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON to enforce data consistency checks on existing data." ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You also might have to put an additional constraint on the table; don't consider myself any kind of expert on temporal tables...`NOCHECK CONSTRAINT constraint_name`  nor am I well versed on the need for the history table to exist etc. here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, I removed the comma, still showing an error, I rebuilt it and the error persists

Comment: @Charlieface, here is the sql version on Visual Studio 2022
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU12) (KB5004524) - 15.0.4153.1 (X64)   Jul 19 2021 15:37:34   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 22000: )

Answer (score 2):

It looked like the target platform needed to be changed.
after I changed clean then rebuild fixed it. see image below

[image: How to change target platform]

Comment: you should accept this as you answer when it lets you